# How do I run two functions on a single button click event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using MVC Extjs and I want two different functions to run on a button's click event. This is my controller code so far:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    runFirst: function(button, e, options) {
        console.log('first function is running');
    },

    runSecond: function(button, e, options) {
        console.log('second function is running');
    },


    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#myButton": {
                click: this.runFirst, runSecond //THIS PART DOESN'T WORK :(
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I can't get both `runFirst` and `runSecond` to run when I click on myButton.

You can download all the code here: https://github.com/nitzaalfinas/Extjs-run-2-function-with-one-click/tree/one

Would you please show me how to run two functions on a single button click?

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing isn't valid Javascript. You can't assign two different values to a single variable (which is all `click:` is)

So, you can achieve it in this way:

```
init: function(application) {
    this.control({
        "#myButton": {
            click: this.runBoth
        }
    });
}

runBoth: function(button, e, options) {
    this.runFirst(button, e, options);
    this.runSecond(button, e, options);
}
```

Or, do it with an anonymous function:

```
init: function(application) {
    this.control({
        "#myButton": {
            click: function(button, e, options) {
                this.runFirst(button, e, options);
                this.runSecond(button, e, options);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 - It doesn't need the new before function. just `click: function(button, e, options)` is good.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but it doesn't work. I will give a complete MVC code. Just wait...

Comment: Please find complete MVC code here https://github.com/nitzaalfinas/Extjs-run-2-function-with-one-click/tree/one
Just download and run on your local server to try and please tell me how to run 2 function on button click